# ¿Cómo extraigo el elemento de una lista que está en una posición específica?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo una lista:

```
lista=[4,5,9,25,16]
```

y quiero saber el dato de la posición 3 (me tendría que salir 25).

¿Hay un comando para eso? ¿Cuál es la forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. ¿Qué llevas hasta ahora? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores te ha dado? Si das más datos es más fácil ayudarte :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar los corchetes para acceder a la posición de la lista.

```
lista = [4,5,9,25,16] 
print( lista[3] )
```

Este trozo de código imprimiría por consola el número *25* cómo tú dices. Échale un ojo a la [sección de arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp) de w3chools para más detalles. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

```
lista = [4,5,9,25,16] 
print(lista[3])
```

también te vale

```
print (lista[-2])
```

Esto es así porque Python trata las listas de esta manera

> Hacia la derecha —> [0-1-2-3-4-5...]
>
> Hacia la izquierda desde el final [...-5-4-3-2-1.] <—

o si lo prefieres , y quisieses buscar un dato y saber su posición

```
for i in lista:
    if i==25:
         print (lista.index(i))
```